# Why does the Shinigami eye deal exist?

Tags: death-note

From Shinigami's perspective, why would they take that deal? As we know they can write a human's name in the notebook and they'll get the remaining lifespan of that human added to theirs. So why would they bother giving away the eyes?

Comment: I primarily think that it is just for their amusement.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Theory # 1: The entertainment
As It is  known that The shinigami don’t normally drop their deathnote in the human world but living forever is certainly getting old for them. The one’s who do it have some motives and one of them can be entertainment. To make it fair, the “half-Life” rule was made. Instead of giving shinigami eyes away, they might might what a person to become more insane after losing literally a huge portion of their life.
 OR, They want to keep the fun going. Giving a person Shinigami eyes as a last option when their host is against the walls. This wouldn’t be Fun at all without such High stakes.

Theory #2: The Power Struggle
As the name suggest, the shinigami eyes belong to the Shinigami. This wasn’t stated in the series, but it is quite possible that it takes a Toll on Shinigami to give shinigami eyes to their unfortunate friend. After-all they are sharing their own power with someone else. OR, this rule is to stop someone from killing all Humanity. One with the shinigami eyes for so long might kill people at much faster rate than usual. It is easy to lift a weight, but you can only keep it in the air for a limited time. Shinigami might find it difficult to some exent to share their own eyes and it is possible that they can maintain it for a limited number of years. If they take the entire lifespan of a person, they’ll have again find someone else to use the deathnote, which is an unnecessary hassle.

(whenever i do  better theories, i’ll add them Here.)

Comment: Your second theory has some loopholes. Shinigamis have nothing to lose from the eye deal. They are immortal creatures anyway. I merely think it is for their amusement or to make the work of the human who gets the death note easier

Comment: You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's simply to add to their amusement, so they have something interesting to experience. After all, the Shinigami realm is quite a dull, sad place, and living a life without a bit of fun is depressing, especially for a Shinigami since they're practically immortal. I mean, Ryuk did drop the Death Note into the human world just because he was bored.